# cannot create child node for child node of jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

Here is my code:

```
function CreateNodeFolder() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: "Default.aspx/GetJson",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                eval("var dataobj=" + msg.d);
                for(var i=dataobj.length-1; i>=0;i--) {
                    $("#MainTree").jstree("create_node",$('#A'),"inside",{ data:dataobj[i].TableName,attr : { id : dataobj[i].TableName }  },false,false);
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            },
        });
    }
    function CreateChildNode() {
        $("#MainTree").jstree("create_node",$('#'+NodeClickName+''),"inside",{ data:"C",attr : { id : "C" }  },false,false);
    }
```

I have a root node which haves ID = "A", first I create node from JSon data. After that, when I use double click event to call CreateChildNode. It doesn't create child node for nodes I create from JSon. It only creates for root node. Please help me to find out why child node can't be created for nodes loading from JSON data.Here is code for calling 
double click event.

```
(#MainTree).jstree({..}).bind("dblclick.jstree", function (event) {
                   var node = $(event.target).closest("li");
                   NodeClickName = node[0].id;
                    inty3 = setInterval(CreateChildNode, 50);
                });
```

Here is how I created root node:

```
$("#MainTree,#SubTree").jstree({

                "json_data": {
                    "data": [{ "data": 'Select node', "state": 'open', "attr": { "id": 'A' } }],
                },

                "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "dnd", "crrm", "contextmenu"],
            })
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure but doesn't .closest("li") select ancestor , were you trying to access .children("li")

Comment: oh..i tried as you said..but it got worse..It didn't create node for root node too..

Comment: what do you get in $(event.target) ? Do you get the node element?

Comment: yup..that's right..i used it to get the node.id..if I console.log(NodeClickName), it returned right ID of node I clicked

Comment: if NodeClickName is giving the correct id , then the only thing you need to check is $('#'+NodeClickName+'') , it should be working.

Comment: hmm..as I said, when I click root node, it created a new child node. That's mean perhaps $('#'+NodeClickName+'') work well..But it didn't affect with Json nodes..I have post my root node code..Please see above..

Comment: last suggestion i can make is try "create" event instead of "create_node" to see if that changes anything.

Comment: okay..it had affected..but it doesn't create child nodes. It created root node if I click JSon node..If i click original root node,I create child node..